# Xcode unable to build on Macbook Pro M1

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I tried to build using Xcode 14.0.1 and currently I have node v18.11.0 but it is trying to find v16.16.0.

```
Showing Recent Errors Only
Can't find the '/Users/sdesktop/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/bin/node' binary to build the React Native bundle.  If you have a non-standard Node.js installation, select your project in Xcode, find  'Build Phases' - 'Bundle React Native code and images' and change NODE_BINARY to an  absolute path to your node executable. You can find it by invoking 'which node' in the terminal.
```

Answer (score 0):

if you run `which node` commands in your project folder you will see where the node is coming from.

What I like to do in this case is.

- setup nvm
- create a .nvmrc file with the node version I would like to use ( in this case 16.)
- setup my terminal to auto load the node version when it founds the `.nvmrc` file.

According to nvm instructions here is what I do in my `.zshrc` file:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
  [ -s "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/nvm.sh" ] && \. "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
  [ -s "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm" ] && \. "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```